# Show that the vector space of polynomials R[x] is isomorphic to a proper subspace of itself

Tags: vector-space-isomorphism

Show that the vector space of polynomials R[x] is isomorphic to a proper
subspace of itself:

Vector Space Isomorphism exists when there exists a bijective (one-to-one and onto) linear mapping F:V $\rightarrow$U. 
the coefficient of the polynomials can be written as $(a_0,a_1,a_2...)$. But how to find the subspace?

What about instead to prove the dimension of the the two vector spaces is the same, which means isomorphic? But how to do it?

Comment: *Proper* subspace means a subspace that is not $\Bbb R[x]$.

Comment: Hint: consider $p(x) \mapsto x p(x)$.

Comment: If it helps, you might want to forget the fact they're polynomials, and just think of them as sequences $(a_0, a_1, \ldots)$ where each $a_i \in R$. There is nothing polynomial-specific being used here.

Answer (score 3):

First, note that you can't do this with finite dimensional vector spaces. You have to come up with a linear transformation which is one-to-one but not onto. Any linear transformation is determined by what happens to the vectors in any basis. Use the standard basis for $R[x]$, that is, $x^n$ where $n\ge 0$. You have to map each $x^n$ to a polynomial such that the mapping is one-to-one. One way to do this is to map $x^n$ to a polynomial of degree $n+1$. You can check this ensures that only the zero polynomial maps to zero. You can check that it is not onto because, for example, $x^0$ is not the image of any polynomial. These two facts depend on looking at the leading term of polynomials and seeing that no nonzero polynomial is a linear combination of polynomials of lesser degrees.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Consider $p(x) \mapsto p(x^2)$.

This acts on a sequence of coefficients (which is all a polynomial is) by inserting zeros between them:
$$(a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n,0,0,0,\dots) \mapsto (a_0,0,a_1,0,a_2,\dots,a_{n-1},0,a_n,0,0,0,\dots)$$
 and so you can recover one from the other.

Comment: Can you show a bit more hint I am very new to this topic. Thank you!

Comment: So you mean for the polynomials, just inserts 0 in between and it constructs a subspace that it is isomorphic to?

Comment: I got the idea but how to show that it is one-to-one and onto?

Comment: @stedmoaoa, just use the function definition I gave.